How to import Ultralytics without an Error?
When I try to import Ultralytics, I get the following error:
Te installation is successful but the issue in "No package"
<ipython-input-4-ef7a9f069429> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('pip', 'install ultralytics  # install')
----> 2 from ultralytics import YOLO, checks, hub
      3 
      4 checks()  # checks

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ultralytics/__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 import os
----> 6 import package
      7 
      8 # Set ENV variables (place before imports)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'

